# Vuejs generating click event in next button after pressing enter input

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm encountering a very strange case.

I've build a very simple example in order to present my problem.

I've 3 files : App.vue, todo2.vue, todoI.vue.
App.vue has 1 component (todo2.vue). todo2.vue has 1 component (todoI.vue).

You'll find under the code of todo2 and todoI.

The problem I'm facing is that when i press enter in the input text id `#checkboxAdd`, it triggers an event on the next button.

In the code below when pressing enter in the input text `#checkboxAdd`, it triggers the click event on the first iteration of my todoI button, which in my example calls the function del (`@click="del()"`), which `console.log(this)`, logging the first iteration of the component todoI.

What is even stranger is that when I add a button just after the input text, add a `@click` to `console.log` the event, it is indeed called (instead of calling the button of the first iteration of todoI).

Does anyone understand why this happens ? Is this something I'm doing wrong ?

**todo2.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div>
            <form @submit.prevent="">
                <div class="mb-3 input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkboxAdd" aria-describedby="checkboxAdd">
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAdd" aria-describedby="inputAdd" v-model="tempI">
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <todoI v-for="(it, k) in todos" v-model="it.v" :key="k" @delItem="del(it)"></todoI>
                </ul>
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

import todoI from './todoI.vue'

export default {
    name:"todo2",
    components: {todoI},
    data: function(){
        return {
            todos: [
                {v:{
                    val: "Bread",
                    checked: false
                }},
                {v:{
                    val: "Fruits",
                    checked: false
                }},
                {v:{
                    val: "Ironing",
                    checked: false
                }}
            ],
            tempI: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        del (it){
            this.todos = this.todos.filter(i => i!==it)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**todoI.vue**:

```
<template>
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex align-items-center" @mouseover="btnShow=true" @mouseleave="btnShow=false">
        <input type="checkbox" class="me-4" v-model="value.checked">
        <div class="w-100" :class="value.checked ? checkedClass : '' ">{{ value.val }}</div>
        <div class="flex-shrink-1">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-close" v-show="btnShow" @click="del()"></button> 
        </div>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"todoI",
    props:{
        value: Object
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            checkedClass:['text-decoration-line-through', 'text-muted'],
            btnShow: false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        del(){
            console.log(this)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simple use @keypress or @keydown

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAdd" v-model="tempI" @keypress.enter.prevent />
```

or

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAdd" v-model="tempI" @keydown.enter.prevent = "">
```

Comment: Indeed swaping keyup by keydown or keypress prevents this behaviour. Meaning that the click is triggered when pressing down. But do you know why this happens ?

Comment: The reason is When filling out a form, pressing enter in a textbox should submit the form. This is known as an implicit form submission. Despite being vital for assistive technologies and an important user convenience, many web forms prevent it for one reason or another

Comment: I doubt that the problem comes from the form being submitting since the form already contains the mention `@submit.prevent=""`

Comment: Anyways pls consider accepting and upvoting my solution if your problem is resolved..thanks:)

Comment: My question wasn't about finding a way to make this code work, I already had another way, my question was about understanding the process that could explain why this happened in order to better understand Vuejs. As a reminder, the question was "Does anyone understand why this happens ?", from your answer I understand you don't, this is the reason why I won't accept your answer for now (but did upvoting it). I will gladly accept an answer (like yours if edited) once an explication has been given.